# Prolog program to find the killer

Tags: prolog

In an exercise I'm trying to write a program in Prolog that should help the police to find the killer. My code looks as follows:

```
student(alexander).
student(tobias).
student(michael).
student(peter).
passed(alexander,chemistry).
passed(peter,history).
passed(tobias,maths).
passed(michael,english).
failed(alexander,english).
failed(peter,chemistry).
failed(tobias,chemistry).
failed(alexander,chemistry).
passed(X, maths) :- failed(X, english), failed(X, history).
passed(X, english) :- failed(X, history), passed(X,maths).
passed(X, economics) :- passed(X, english), failed(X, history).
failed(X, history) :- failed(X, economics), passed(X, chemistry).
failed(X, english) :- failed(X, chemistry), passed(X, history).
killer(X):-student(X),failed(X,economics).*
```

The following facts were established:

1. Every student that failed both English and History, passed Maths.
2. Every student that failed history but passed math, passed English.
3. Every student that failed history but passed English, passed economics.
4. Every student that failed economics but passed chemistry, failed history.
5. Every student that failed chemistry but passed history, failed English.
6. Alexander failed English but passed chemistry.
7. Peter failed chemistry and passed history.
8. Tobias failed history and passed maths.
9. Michael failed maths and passed English.

One of the four students has killed his professor. When the medical examiner examined the body, he found a piece of paper in his right hand: “the
killer failed economics”.

How can I now relate passed to failed?

Comment: (1) I dont understand what the caret '^' means in this context, could you explain what it is intended to represent? (2) There are no variables in you example, only atoms: then, your 'every student...' propositions are not quantified. (3) Last but not least, you did not define what a 'killer' is; I don't know this puzzle, could you provide more informations?

Comment: The caret '^' means AND. I need to find the killer following the established facts

Comment: In the asserted sentences there is no reference to any killer. Can you tell us in natural language what is a killer?

Comment: Sorry I have completely forgot a part. One of the four students has killed the professor and after the murder a piece of paper has been found with the following fact “the killer failed economics”.

Comment: A simple rule `killer(X) :- failed(X, economics)` should be enough then.

Comment: I had already that rule bu the program's output is false.

Comment: You have some rules missing. Your problem should be program termination and not direct failure.

Comment: Try to solve this problem using the pencil. See if you have a rule that Prolog could use for every inference you make yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I have some observations regarding your representation.

First, your predicates `english/1`, `maths/1` are not enough to express the fact that a particular student passed an exam. If you assert `english(failed)`, then what student is this phrase about? You need to include the student in the relation (e.g. `english(michael, passed)`).

In addition, I suggest you to consider the `failed` or `passed` result as being the relation. You could use two such relations `failed/2` and `passed/2`, with `failed(S, E)` meaning that student `S` failed exam `E`. E.g:

```
∀ X : student(X) ∧ failed(X, english) ∧ failed(X, history) → passed(X, maths)
```

would be partially represented in Prolog as follows:

```
passed(X, maths) :- student(X), failed(X, english), failed(X, history).
```

Of course, you can drop the `student(X)` condition if the first argument of `failed/2` is always a student.

---

Now, the sentence

> Every student that failed both English and History, passed Maths.

could be formalized in FOL as follows:

```
∀ X : student(X) ∧ failed(X, english) ∧ failed(X, history) → passed(X, maths)
```

Using `A → B ≡ ¬A ∨ B`, you find the equivalent forms:

```
∀ X : ¬student(X) ∨ ¬failed(X, english) ∨ ¬failed(X, history) ∨ passed(X, maths)
```

(in Disjunctive Normal Form), or back to implication:

```
∀ X : ¬passed(X, maths) ∧ failed(X, english) ∧ failed(X, history) → ¬student(X)
∀ X : student(X) ∧ ¬passed(X, maths) ∧ failed(X, history) → ¬failed(X, english)
∀ X : student(X) ∧ failed(X, english) ∧ ¬passed(X, maths) → ¬failed(X, history)
```

Be careful, Prolog uses [closed world assumption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation_as_failure) (`¬student(X)` is not `\+ student(X)`), therefore you cannot directly translate the above rules to Prolog.

**Assuming that every student took all exams** and using `∀ X : ∀ E : passed(X, E) ⟺ ¬failed(X, E)`, you can infer the following clauses:

```
∀ X : student(X) ∧ failed(X, maths) ∧ failed(X, history) → passed(X, english)
∀ X : student(X) ∧ failed(X, english) ∧ failed(X, maths) → passed(X, history)
```

So, from that phrase (*Every student that failed both English and history passed maths*) you should extract 3 separate rules in Prolog:

```
passed(X, maths) :- student(X), failed(X, english), failed(X, history).
passed(X, english) :- student(X), failed(X, maths), failed(X, history).
passed(X, history) :- student(X), failed(X, english), failed(X, maths).
```

If it's not the case that all students took all exams, you should introduce some predicate `tooks(Student, Exam)`, but then the above explanations get more complicated.

---

Strictly regarding representation, another variant is to use a single predicate `exam_result/3` with the following meaning: `exam_result(Student, Exam, Result)` represents the fact that student `Student` took exam `Exam` and its result is `Result`.

```
result(alexander, chemistry, passed).
```

The idea is not to take the above representation suggestion as a rule.

---

A second observation, you represent a lot of information using a single predicate, `killer/3`.

```
killer(alexander,english(failed),chemistry(passed)).
```

It is more intuitive to split this in separate, more clear, relations:

```
killer(alexander).
failed(alexander, english).
passed(chemistry, alexander).
```

It is easier to check if a particular student passed or failed a particular exam. In addition, it is hard to extend your `killer/3` predicate (and all the rules that use that predicate) if students have more (or less) than two exams.

---

To find a student that failed a specific exam (e.g. economics) you can ask Prolog:

```
?- failed(Student, economics).
Student=alexander ;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

**See the problem as CSP**

Another approach to solving the puzzle is to see it as a Constrain Satisfaction Problem. A CSP is defined by a set of variables, a domain for each variable and a set of constraints that express relations between those variables. Solving such a problem means assigning a value for each variable from its domain such that all constraints are satisfied.

In this case, a possible representation is to see each student-exam pair as a variable that can take one of these two values: `[passed, failed]`. The constraints will be exactly the statements given in the question. One possibility to represent a solution in Prolog is using a list `Exams` containing structures `exam(Student, Exam, Result)` (e.g. `Exams = [exam(alexander, history, passed), exam(tobias, maths, failed), ...]`). This list has exactly one element for each student-exam pair.

In a naive approach, all possible solutions are generated in turn and checked against the constraints.

**Checking constraints**

Now, to check a restriction as *Alexander failed English* is trivial (use `member/2`). To check if

> Every student that failed both English and History, passed Maths.

you might need to reformulate it:

> it is not the case that exists a student that failed both English and History and did not pass Maths.

See why those two are equivalent:

```
∀ X : failed(X, english) ∧ failed(X, history) → passed(X, maths)
≡
∀ X : ¬failed(X, english) ∨ ¬failed(X, history) ∨ passed(X, maths)
≡
¬( ¬(∀ X : ¬failed(X, english) ∨ ¬failed(X, history) ∨ passed(X, maths)))
≡
¬( ∃ X : failed(X, english) ∧ failed(X,history) ∧ ¬passed(X, maths))
```

Assuming that every student took all exams and using `∀ X : ∀ E : passed(X, E) ⟺ ¬failed(X, E)`:

```
¬( ∃ X : failed(X, english) ∧ failed(X,history) ∧ failed(X, maths))
```

This last form can be easily transformed into a constraint for a candidate solution:

```
\+ ( member(exam(X, english, failed), Exams),
     member(exam(X, history, failed), Exams),
     member(exam(X, maths, failed), Exams) )
```

*Later edit:*
This is **not an efficient way** to tackle CSP (there are libraries for that and better algorithms and heuristics: forward checking, AC3, value ordering, variable ordering, etc.), but it represents a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on this nice puzzle, but I've totally rewritten the code.
Note that your question still has some incongruence, like

```
passed(alexander,chemistry).
...
failed(alexander,chemistry).
```

Anyway, mutually recursive rules in Prolog can easily lead to non terminating programs, so the 'truth representation' is better handled like data, not rules...

```
:- module(killer, [killer/1, possible_killer/1]).

killer(S) :-
    student(S, Facts),
    sure(Facts, Results),
    compatible(-economics, Results).

possible_killer(S) :-
    student(S, Facts),
    sure(Facts, Results),
    % memberchk(-economics, Results).
    \+ memberchk(+economics, Results).

student(alexander, [-english, +chemistry]). % Alexander failed English but passed chemistry.
student(peter, [-chemistry, +history]).     % Peter failed chemistry and passed history.
student(tobias, [-history, +maths]).        % Tobias failed history and passed maths.
student(michael, [-maths, +english]).       % Michael failed maths and passed English.

rule([-english, -history], +maths   ). % Every student that failed both English and History, passed Maths.
rule([-history, +maths], +english   ). % Every student that failed history but passed math, passed English.
rule([-history, +english], +economics). % Every student that failed history but passed English, passed economics.
rule([-economics, +chemistry], -history).   % Every student that failed economics but passed chemistry, failed history.
rule([-chemistry, +history], -english). % Every student that failed chemistry but passed history, failed English.

sure(Facts, Results) :-
    rule(IF, THEN),
    forward(IF, THEN, Facts, Update),
    !, sure(Update, Results).
sure(Facts, Facts).

forward(Conditions, Consequence, Facts, [Consequence|Facts]) :-
    \+ memberchk(Consequence, Facts),
    forall(member(C, Conditions), memberchk(C, Facts)).

invert(+C, -C).
invert(-C, +C).

compatible(R, Results) :-
    invert(R, I),
    \+ memberchk(I, Results),
    rule(Conditions, Fact),
    memberchk(R, Conditions),
    forall(member(C, Conditions), compatible(Fact, [C|Results])).
compatible(R, Results) :-
    memberchk(R, Results).
```

Results:

```
?- possible_killer(X).
X = alexander ;
X = peter ;
X = michael.
```

The 'positive' knowledge is sufficient to just rule out Tobias.
We need a better way to explore instead the 'negative' knowledge, that as Tudor noted, in Prolog can be problematic to assess.

```
?- killer(X).
X = michael ;
false.
```